# Trying to return -1 or char

Tags: c, string, function, character

```
void main() {
    int letter;
    letter = myToLower('v');
    printf("The new letter is: %c", letter);
}

int myToLower(char ch) {
    if (isupper(ch)) return tolower(ch); else return -1;
}
```

when im trying Upper Case the program works and return the letter in lower case, when im trying lower case the program doesnt return -1.
someone have an idea how can i return both of them?

Comment: C and C++ are two distinct languages; please do not tag both. I removed the C++ tag as your code looks like C, and will not compile as C++ as written.

Comment: The `-1` value for `%c` probably isn't any character that resembles that shape. The screen character output is system-dependent, and `%c` certainly won't output "-1".

Comment: For me [it works](https://godbolt.org/z/En6v3Y3xz) or you mean the way the character is displayed?

Comment: `if (letter != -1) printf("The new letter is: %c\n", letter); else printf("The letter is unchanged.\n");`

Comment: Change `%c` to `%d` and see what happens. BTW what output did you expect?

Comment: Have you considered returning `ch` unchanged?

Comment: @Eljay thanks it works :) i just added those lines if (letter != -1) printf("the new letter is %c", letter); else printf("%d", letter)

Comment: Why check `isupper` first? Just `int myToLower(unsigned char ch) { return tolower(ch); }` - Note the `unsigned char`. You should always cast to `unsigned char` when using these `ctype.h` functions.

Comment: Try `printf("myToLower returned %d\n", letter);`.

Comment: I posted the answer in the comments in a answer post for future users.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are returning a `-1` value, and when `printf` looks at the `%c` in it, it looks at the corresponding `valist` argument, and it finds `-1`. The output of this is system dependant. The fix is this: (as given by Eljay)

```
if (letter != -1) 
{
    printf("The new letter is: %c\n", letter); 
}
else 
{
    printf("The letter is unchanged.\n");
}
```

It is usually best to but in braces because it is more debuggable that way. You can see where the statements start and end.